# Using the assign() method on the JSDO to update OE table information

Tags: javascript, rest, progress-4gl, openedge

My app draws data from an OpenEdge table and uses a Business Entity and Rest Service to serve up the data through the PASOE. I am developing on the JavaScript side and have little to no experience with OE beyond generating Business Entities with CRUD operations for my services to use.

What I'm trying to do is update a single field of a single record from true to false by using the JSDO's assign method. I keep getting a 500 error that says it was unable to find a a WHERE STRING and that it needs KEYS and INDEXES, and all that stuff. The problem is, I almost certain I'm using assign() wrong, but I can't be sure. The documentation on it is not very specific as to how to us it and what parameters it wants in order to update or assign anything. 
I feel like this example is woefully vague. What should "update-object" look like?

Help!

Thanks in advance.

PS. I can create a code snippet of what I'm trying to do if need be, but my question is pretty general.

Comment: You're more likely to get an accurate answer if you provide a more accurate question - so a code snippet would help. Also, what version of Progress?

Comment: An 500 error especially with references to the WHERE STRING AND KEYS AND INDEXES is a problem in your ABL backend logic. Please make sure you start your AppServer with -debugalert and -errorstack and provide exact error messages - including stack trace - from the AppServer logfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the delayed response. My issue was purely my lack of knowledge involving OpenEdge itself. My first solution, that I was able to figure out all on my own, was simply to add a KEYS statements in the data-source definition of my class file like so:

DEFINE DATA-SOURCE srcWHS_TEMP_LOC FOR sandbox.WHS_TEMP_LOC KEYS (TEMP_ID).

I did this on a field that I knew was unique. For my other table I needed a combination of two fields to create a unique ID, so our resident OpenEdge expert was able to add them for me. Everything works well now.